# How to sum individual columns of Radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

Via searching I can see how to sum the values of radio buttons in multiple columns into a single total.  How are several columns of radio buttons summed within their own column totals?

I've used this to sum all columns into a single total:

```
function setRadios()
 {

  var inputs = document.getElementById('myForm').getElementsByClassName('myRadio');
  function sumRadios(){
var total = 0, 
    oForm = this.form;

for(var x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++){
  if (inputs[x].checked) total += parseInt(inputs[x].value);
}

// Defines the field that totals the selections
oForm.elements['myxTN1'].value = total.toFixed(0);

  }

 for(var y = 0; y < inputs.length; y++){
inputs[y].onclick = sumRadios;
}

}
onload = setRadios;
```

If you have 2 or more columns of radio buttons, how do you sum for each column?  Only one Entity is allowed to have each individual item so there is a fixed grand total.

In my JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/babakt/C4Swr/ selecting any button totals in one column.

How to fix so that Entity 1 selects item 1 for a total of 1; Entity 2 selects item 2 for a total of 2; Entity 3 selects item 3 for a total of 10 and if Entity 1 selects item 3 the total for it changes to 11 and Entity 3 is 0?

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using a [colgroup](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/tabular-data.html#the-colgroup-element) element. You can also use sequentially named form controls (col1_1, col1_2, col2_1, col2_2, etc.) or different classes (as you are already doing).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly: simply give the buttons and result field in each column a common class name (e.g. `col1`, `col2`, `col3`) and loop over these columns individually, using `getElementsByClassName('col1')` etc.

Comment: I think I'm making some progress.  Still totaling 1 column but displaying in 3 column totals. Not using getElementsByClassName correctly I believe.  Tried multiple variations and searching. http://jsfiddle.net/babakt/2khVw/ If a button is deselected its not updating the total either.